How to delete 2 rows in every 3 in Google Sheets?
I have a large sheet and I want to:
Row 1: Keep This Data
Row 2: Delete this row
Row 3: Delete this row
Row 4: Keep this Data
Row 5: Delete this row
Row 6: Delete this row
Row 7: Keep this Data
etc for like 300 rows.
I've found formulas for deleting even rows and odd rows but my brain can't adjust it for this specific scenario. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Because of the odd numbers, if Row 2+3 are deleted, data shifts, and then the next grouping to delete becomes 3+4.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question and insert a table of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a blank sheet maker that lets you share safely.

Choose Insert > Sheet and put this formula in cell A1 of the new sheet:
=query(Sheet1!A1:D, "skipping 3", 0)

Replace Sheet1!A1:D with the actual location of the data.
See query().

Use Filter to Retrieve and Display Data
You may use this script that should work with what you'd like to do.
Code:
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = ss.getDataRange();
  var values = data.getValues();
  var out = values.filter((x, i) => i % 3 == 0);
  data.clearContent();
  ss.getRange(1, 1, out.length, out[0].length).setValues(out);
}

This script visually makes it look like the rows have been deleted, as the data shifts upward when Apps Script is used for row deletion.
The code snippet var out = values.filter((x, i) => i % 3 == 0); filters the array to retain only every third row, commencing with the initial row (index 0).
Sample Output before running the code:

Sample Output after running the code:


Perhaps replace data.getLastColumn() with out[0].length to make the code work with ranges that start at a column other than A?

@doubleunary, thank you for the heads-up. I have updated my code accordingly.

Another possibility, that actually deletes rows as desired:
function deleteRows() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  let i = 1;  // Enter here the row number at which to start (this row is kept).
  while (++i < sheet.getMaxRows()) {
    sheet.deleteRows(i, 2);
  }
  if (i === sheet.getMaxRows()) sheet.deleteRow(i);
}

Note that the algorithm applies to all rows, regardless of their content, so empty rows at the end of the document will also be deleted in a two-out-of-three fashion.
